# how can i access the folders in Dropbox php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

i am trying to read and write a folder in Dropbox. so i have registered my app in DropBox
..

Details of my App is..

**Permission type**     App folder

**App folder name**     hello

now the "hello "folder is in this directory at the moment

https://www.dropbox.com/home/Apps/

so when i do this

```
  $files = $this->DropboxApi->ls( );
        pr($files);
```

the result i am getting is this

```
Array
(
    [Dropbox] => Array
        (
            [hash] => *****************
            [thumb_exists] => 
            [bytes] => 0
            [path] => /
            [is_dir] => 1
            [size] => 0 bytes
            [root] => app_folder
            [contents] => Array
                (
                )

            [icon] => folder
        )

)
```

so the problem is i dont know how can i access the folder **hello**

what should be the path

```
$files = $this->DropboxApi->ls('Path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to write file name `myfile.extension` in folder `myfolder` then your upload path will be:

`<root>/myfolder/myfile.extension`

then your endpoint url to upload file will be:

`https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/myfolder/myfile.extension`

In case of download you first need to send request to endpoint:

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/media/dropbox/myfolder/myfile.extension`

In response you will get json like: `{"url":"here is downloadable link"}`

To see contents/details in folder, endpoint will be:

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/hello?list=true`

Comment: according to my situation what it should be ??

Comment: sorry it was the first time i am integrating dropbox with php ...at this time i just want to read the directory

Comment: means you need details of file in "hello" folder? @hellosheikh

Comment: yup exactly ..because at the moment i just want to check whether i can access it or not ..

Comment: @hellosheikh see answer. you endpoint will be `https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/hello?list=true`

Comment: so should i do this $this->DropboxApi->ls(metadata/dropbox/hello?list=true);    i have to pass path here ... rest is assured by plugin itself.. actually i am working on a cakephp.. so i want to know what path do i write in braces

Comment: I would say try both: ` $this->DropboxApi->ls(metadata/dropbox/hello?list=true);` and ` $this->DropboxApi->ls(/dropbox/hello?list=true);` First one should be successful.

Comment: well this doesn't work as well ... this is the plugin i am using .. at the end of the page there is a details of how to show the directory may be it helps you https://github.com/shama/cakebox

Comment: try:
$files = $this->DropboxApi->ls('hello'); and $files = $this->DropboxApi->ls('dropbox/hello');. I am not sure about path that is start from <root> or not. Also in above comment path must between quotes @hellosheikh

Comment: yup the path is starting from root and i have set the root to sandbox not dropbox .. and i have print the array too above ...

Comment: If your app name is actually "hello" (seems unlikely, since someone probably took that name already?), then my guess is `$this->DropboxApi->ls('/')` or maybe `->ls('')` will list the contents of `Dropbox/Apps/hello`. Basically, the path you use is always relative to your app folder (`Apps/<app name>`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder = $dropbox->GetFiles("hello",false);
```

it return all the files into the hello folder(return array)